# Backbone collection fetches all models but sets only one

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone.js-collections

I know this question has been asked before, but the other answers haven't solve my issue:

View:

```
initialize: ->
   @dataFields = new app.collections.DataFields([], {campaign_id:@id})
   @loadAndRender()

 loadAndRender: ->
   @dataFields.fetch {
   success: ((model, response) ->
     debugger
     @render()
   ), this
   error: ->
}
```

Collection and Model:

```
window.app.models.DataField = Backbone.Model.extend(
  initialize: (models, options) ->
    @campaign_id = options.campaign_id
    @id = options.id

  url: ->
    if @id
      '/campaigns/' + @campaign_id + '/data_fields/' + @id
    else
      '/campaigns/' + @campaign_id + '/data_fields'
)

window.app.collections.DataFields = Backbone.Collection.extend(
  model: window.app.models.DataField
  parse : (response, options) ->
    debugger
    response

  initialize: (models, options) ->
    @campaign_id = options.campaign_id

  url: ->
    '/campaigns/' + @campaign_id + '/data_fields'
)
```

The network logs show that all of the 'data_fields' were pulled correctly from the remote service.

The first debugger statement in the first block allowed me to verify that although all the records in the collect made it over the wire, only the first model was saved into the collection.

The second debugger statement in the second block allowed me to verify that in the 'response' object does, in fact, contains the json for all the models.  The data returned from the service looks like this:

```
[{"id":78,"name":"campaign_provider_id","campaign_id":197,"description":"campaign specific identifier","data_type":"string","required_flag":true,"unique_flag":null,"system_flag":true,"display_name":"CampaignProviderID","display_order":1},{"id":79,"name":"campaign_api_key","campaign_id":197,"description":"campaign specific API key","data_type":"string","required_flag":true,"unique_flag":null,"system_flag":true,"display_name":"CampaignAPIKey","display_order":2},{"id":80,"name":"provider_api_key","campaign_id":197,"description":"provider specific API key","data_type":"string","required_flag":true,"unique_flag":null,"system_flag":true,"display_name":"ProviderAPIKey","display_order":3},{"id":81,"name":"email","campaign_id":197,"description":"valid email address of individual","data_type":"email","required_flag":true,"unique_flag":true,"system_flag":null,"display_name":"Email","display_order":4},{"id":82,"name":"first_name","campaign_id":197,"description":"individual's surname","data_type":"string","required_flag":null,"unique_flag":null,"system_flag":null,"display_name":"FirstName","display_order":5},{"id":83,"name":"last_name","campaign_id":197,"description":"individual's family name","data_type":"string","required_flag":null,"unique_flag":null,"system_flag":null,"display_name":"LastName","display_order":6},{"id":84,"name":"company","campaign_id":197,"description":"company or organization that the individual represents","data_type":"string","required_flag":true,"unique_flag":null,"system_flag":null,"display_name":"Company","display_order":7},{"id":85,"name":"country","campaign_id":197,"description":"country where individual or company resides","data_type":"string","required_flag":true,"unique_flag":null,"system_flag":null,"display_name":"Country","display_order":8},{"id":86,"name":"postal_code","campaign_id":197,"description":"zip or postal code where individual or company resides","data_type":"string","required_flag":true,"unique_flag":null,"system_flag":null,"display_name":"ZipCode","display_order":9},{"id":87,"name":"network_size","campaign_id":197,"description":"estimate of the number of individuals in company or organization","data_type":"integer","required_flag":true,"unique_flag":null,"system_flag":null,"display_name":"NetworkSize","display_order":10},{"id":88,"name":"asset_name","campaign_id":197,"description":"name of entity (product, event, service) associated with this lead","data_type":"email","required_flag":true,"unique_flag":null,"system_flag":null,"display_name":"AssetName","display_order":11}]
```

If you put the data into a ison parser you will notice that there are no models with the same ID value...

Why doesn't my collection contain all the models fetched from the service?

UPDATE Based on 'mu is to short' answer:

---

Based on mu's answer below, I changed my collection model to look like:

```
window.app.models.DataField = Backbone.Model.extend(
  url: ->
      '/campaigns/' + @get('campaign_id') + '/data_fields/' + @get('id')
)

window.app.collections.DataFields = Backbone.Collection.extend(
  model: window.app.models.DataField
  url: ->
    '/campaigns/' + @get('campaign_id') + '/data_fields'
)
```

And when I call the following:

```
app.views.DataFields = Backbone.View.extend(
  events:
    'submit #delete-campaign form': 'onSubmitDeleteCampaign'
    'click .data-field-row [name="required_flag"]' : 'onClickRequiredFlag'
    'click .data-field-row [name="unique-radios"]' : 'onClickUniqueFlag'

  initialize: ->
    @dataFields = new app.collections.DataFields(campaign_id:@id)
    @loadAndRender()

  loadAndRender: ->
    @dataFields.fetch {
      success: (model, response) =>
        debugger
        @render()
      , this
      error: ->
    }
```

Now when I call @dataFields.fetch, it fetches /campaigns/undefined/data_fields.  Before it was actually correctly creating the URL string with a campaign ID.  The problem was that while the response was correctly returning all the models, the collection was only setting the first model in the list.

Comment: What is `new app.collections.DataFields(campaign_id:@id)` supposed to do? That doesn't match the arguments for a collection constructor.

Comment: That looks like it was a mistake.  Right now the collection makes the correct service call when i instantiate like this:    `@dataFields = new app.collections.DataFields([], {campaign_id:@id})`

Comment: The updated model and collection are fine (http://jsfiddle.net/mydt17cj/). Can you reproduce your problem in that fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments for your model's `initialize` are wrong. You're saying:

```
initialize: (models, options) ->
```

but [they're actually](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** `new Model([attributes], [options])`

This means that you're always saying `@id = options.id` and that's just a complicated way of saying `@id = undefined` and all your models end up with the same `@id` (which just happens to be `undefined`).

Also, Backbone will take care of the `@id` by itself, you shouldn't try to set that yourself. So your `initialize` should look more like this:

```
initialize: (attributes, options) ->
  @campaign_id = attributes.campaign_id
```

You could also skip `@campaign_id` completely and just use `@get('campaign_id')` (or `@attributes.campaign_id` if you think `@get` is too slow but please don't waste your time with this sort of micro-optimization); if you do this, then you don't need an `initialize` at all.

---

While I'm here, Backbone's `extend` and CoffeeScript's `extends` work together so you can say:

```
class window.app.models.DataField extends Backbone.Model
```

and The Right Thing will happen.

Also, you'd usually use a `=>` instead of `_.bind` in CoffeeScript so you'd say things like:

```
loadAndRender: ->
  @dataFields.fetch(
    success: (model, response) =>
      debugger
      @render()
  )
```

You don't have to do this of course and sometimes `_.bind` makes sense even in CoffeeScript.

Comment: But the campaign ID is not undefined.  It is set correctly when i instantiate the collection...  Please see much changes above.